# How can I remove duplicate nodes in XQuery?

Tags: duplicates, xquery

I have an XML document I generate on the fly, and I need a function to eliminate any duplicate nodes from it.

My function looks like:

```
declare function local:start2() {
    let $data := local:scan_books()
    return <books>{$data}</books>
};
```

Sample output is:

```
<books>
  <book>
    <title>XML in 24 hours</title>
    <author>Some Guy</author>  
  </book>
  <book>
    <title>XML in 24 hours</title>
    <author>Some Guy</author>  
  </book>
</books>
```

I want just the one entry in my books root tag, and there are other tags, like say pamphlet in there too that need to have duplicates removed. Any ideas?

---

Updated following comments. By unique nodes, I mean remove multiple occurrences of nodes that have the exact same content and structure.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**A simpler and more direct one-liner XPath solution**:

*Just use the following XPath expression*:

```
  /*/book
        [index-of(/*/book/title, 
                  title
                 )
                  [1]
        ]
```

**When applied, for example, on the following XML document**:

```
<books>
    <book>
        <title>XML in 24 hours</title>
        <author>Some Guy</author>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>Food in Seattle</title>
        <author>Some Guy2</author>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>XML in 24 hours</title>
        <author>Some Guy</author>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>Food in Seattle</title>
        <author>Some Guy2</author>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>How to solve XPAth Problems</title>
        <author>Me</author>
    </book>
</books>
```

**the above XPath expression selects correctly the following nodes**:

```
<book>
    <title>XML in 24 hours</title>
    <author>Some Guy</author>
</book>
<book>
    <title>Food in Seattle</title>
    <author>Some Guy2</author>
</book>
<book>
    <title>How to solve XPAth Problems</title>
    <author>Me</author>
</book>
```

**The explanation** is simple: For every `book`, select only one of its occurences -- such that its index in *all-books* is the same as the first index of its `title` in *all-titles*.

Comment: Hey Dimitre, thanks for the answer; but if I understand correctly, it depends on all the elements having the same structure which is the built into the query - for example it would show two nodes the same if they had the same title and different authors...

Comment: @Brabster It is not at all clear from your question how the test for inequality/uniqueness should be defined. If you define it, it will help you to find a simpler solution

Comment: This does not seem to work with XPath 1.0, can we get a working XPath 1.0 solution?

Comment: @Abarax: This question is tagged "xquery". XQuery is a superset of XPAth *2.0*. Never anyone was asking for an XPath 1.0 answer. This operation is generally known as *grouping* and in the general case cannot be expressed with a single XPath expression and in the specific cases when such single XPath 1.0 expression exists, it may be inefficient. This is why XSLT 1.0 is tyoically used for efficient grouping -- e.e. the Muenchian grouping method.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev no worries, makes sense. Would this same solution work for multiple fields that define uniqueness? i.e. title and author defines uniqueness

Comment: @Abarax: A similar expression will work -- one needs to specify the concatenation of the fields.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the built-in `distinct-values()` function...

Comment: How can you use that?

Answer (score 3):

A solution inspired by functional programming. This solution is extensible in that you can replace the **"="** comparison by your **custom-built** boolean `local:compare($element1, $element2)` function. This function has **worst-case** quadratic complexity in the length of the list. You could get `n(log n)` complexity by sorting the list **before-hand** and only comparing with the immediate successor.

To my best knowledge, the `fn:distinct-values` (or `fn:distinct-elements`) functions does not allow to use a **custom-built** comparison function.

```
declare function local:deduplicate($list) {
  if (fn:empty($list)) then ()
  else 
    let $head := $list[1],
      $tail := $list[position() > 1]
    return
      if (fn:exists($tail[ . = $head ])) then local:deduplicate($tail)
      else ($head, local:deduplicate($tail))
};

let $list := (1,2,3,4,1,2,1) return local:deduplicate($list)
```

Comment: This solution seems to work. Could you please explain the line "fn:exists($tail[ . = $head ])"? I have modified this to be "$head = $tail" and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by implementing a recursive uniqueness search function, based solely on the text content of my document for uniqueness matching.

```
declare function ssd:unique-elements($list, $rules, $unique) {
    let $element := subsequence($rules, 1, 1)
    let $return :=
    if ($element) then
        if (index-of($list, $element) >= 1) then
            ssd:unique-elements(insert-before($element, 1, $list), subsequence($rules, 2), $unique)
        else <test>
            <unique>{$element}</unique>
            {ssd:unique-elements(insert-before($element, 1, $list), subsequence($rules, 2), insert-before($element, 1, $unique))/*}
            </test>
    else ()
    return $return
};
```

Called as follows:

```
declare function ssd:start2() {
    let $data := ()
    let $sift-this := 
       <test>
           <data>123</data>
           <data>456</data>
           <data>123</data>
           <data>456</data>
           <more-data>456</more-data>
       </test>
    return ssd:unique-elements($data, $sift-this/*, ())/*/*
};

ssd:start2()
```

output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>123</data>
<data>456</data>
```

I guess if you need slightly different equivalence matching, you can alter the matching in the algorithm accordingly. Should get you started at any rate.

Answer (score 1):

What about fn:distinct-values?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this functx function: functx:distinct-deep

No need reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 1):

To remove duplicates I usually use a helper function. In your case it'll look like that:

```
declare function local:remove-duplicates($items as item()*) 
as item()*
{
  for $i in $items
  group by $i
    return $items[index-of($items, $i)[1]]
};

declare function local:start2() {
    let $data := local:scan_books()
    return <books>{local:remove-duplicates($data)}</books>
};
```