# Select distinct-values according to child node in XQuery

Tags: duplicates, unique, xquery

Let's say I have the following XML:

```
<info>
    <channel>
        <A>
          <X>
            <title>title1</title>
          </X>
          <Y value="20"/>
        </A>
    </channel>
    <channel>
        <A>
          <X>
            <title>title1</title>
          </X>
          <Y value="20"/>
        </A>
        <A>
          <X>
            <title>title2</title>
          </X>
          <Y value="20"/>
        </A>
    </channel>
</info>
```

and the following XQuery

```
{
for $A in doc('test.xml')//A
let $TITLE := $A/X/title
where string($A/Y/value) > 20
return
  string($TITLE)
}
```

this, of course, outputs:

```
title1
title1
title2
```

How can I use `distinct-values` in order to remove duplicates? I wonder because `for` essentially only gives me one item per iteration and I can't call `distinct-values` on `$A`. Or is there any other way to remove duplicate output?

The problem is that I need to refer to another node, so basically calling `distinct-values(doc...)` doesn't work, as it doesn't return nodes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***UPDATE***

to filter duplicate *nodes*, use a variation of the xpath from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644384/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-nodes-in-xquery/666265#666265):

```
//A[index-of(//A/X/title, X/title)[1]]
```

this gives you all the `A`s with different `title`s.

you can expand this xpath expression to also filter on `Y` - no need for XQuery [FLWOR](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#id-flwor-expressions).

***UPDATE END***

apply the `distinct-values` to the xpath expression over which you want to iterate:

```
for $title in distinct-values(doc('test.xml')//A/X/@title)
return string($title)
```

or just

```
distinct-values(doc('test.xml')//A/X/@title)
```

Comment: It didn't really work. It selects some nodes, but I can't figure out which ones. There are no duplicates, but some are missing completely. I updated my question again.

Comment: Ok, it seems that it doesn't work when the `A` element is not the root!

Comment: Got it figured out. You might want to update your answer to reflect those changes, but in the end it comes to first iterating over the `channel` elements and then a variation of your line: `for $A in $CHANNEL/A[index-of(//$CHANNEL/A/X/title, X/title)[1]]`